# Ajax response line by line instead of full output

Tags: jquery

I am using a standard Ajax call to a PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#response').data;
    }
});
```

The output is being put here

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

But instead of showing the response once the Ajax call has completed, I want to have it output line by line from the PHP output.

Similar to a "debug" or "logs" style output like this:

[image: buddy.works]

Comment: Assuming `data` in the AJAX callback is an array of the console output, one line per entity, then you can just loop through them, using something like `setTimeout()` to delay moving to the next line. If you'd like more specific help, please edit your question to show the code you've written so we can help you to debug it

Comment: This doesn't appear to be under the control of the JavaScript code you're showing.  If you're attempting to send multiple reponses to the client (one line/response at a time) then it sounds like you're looking for Web Sockets instead of a plain AJAX request/response.

Comment: essentially, the PHP is going to output multiple lines and i want to show each line as it's output. I guess this may need some PHP work also as that'll only display the full ouput once its complete

Comment: Yes it's going to output all lines at once, unless what you are looking for is more a UX approach just showing the end user line by line to keep that "feel of logs", then you could assign the string to a variable, create a "for" loop, and every 10-12 words, do a $('#response').append(dataWords); or something similar.

Comment: @Leo that's exactly it - but i was wondering whether it could output each line as it's echoed or will it only show all lines once the whole script has completed?

Comment: Just by using a for loop it will show all lines of code because it will happen very fast, so maybe you could use a setTimeout(function(){ $('#response').append(dataWords);  },400) inside the for loop so when it appends the string you could see it line by line to mimic the "logs" feel